# Loading an array with the squares of it's subscripts in C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

```
#define N 500

int subscriptSquares[N];

void loadArray(int nums[], int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= (size - 1); i++)
    {
        nums[i] = i * i;
        printf("%i\n", nums[i]);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do more specifically is load an array of size 500 with its subscript squares (so subscriptSquares = {0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, ...250000}). My problem is somewhere along the line the values are shortened. The last value in the array actually becomes 249001 instead of 250000 and so on so forth. I thought it had something to with the data type so I switched it to double but ended up with same values with the obvious annoyance of decimals. `int subscriptSquares[N]` is inside the main function. If you need more information let me know

Comment: A C array of size 500 has indices from 0 to 499. 499 squared is 249001. Your program is doing exactly what it is supposed to. If you want 250000, that would be index 500, the last element in a _501_-element array. See [Off-by-1 error / Fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

Comment: Note that it is conventional to use `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)` rather than `i <= (size - 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have defined an array of size 500. It will contain indices from 0 to 499.

So, the last result of your calculation will be `499*499 = 249001`.

If you want to get the result of `500*500` then you have to declare an array of 501 locations. The below code shows how.

```
#define N 501

int subscriptSquares[N];

void loadArray(int nums[], int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= (size - 1); i++)
    {
        nums[i] = i * i;
        printf("%i\n", nums[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!